Android - BillingLogger: Skipped logging since initialization failed
Testing out in app purchases with the following:
purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
        
    }
};

billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(DonateActivity.this)
    .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
    .enablePendingPurchases(PendingPurchasesParams.newBuilder().enableOneTimeProducts().build())
    .build();
    
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult){
        if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK){
            materialbutton_buy.setEnabled(true);
            //Billing Client ready, query purchases
            QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams = 
                QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductList(
                        ImmutableList.of(
                            Product.newBuilder()
                                .setProductId("android.test.purchased")
                                .setProductType(ProductType.INAPP)
                                .build()))
                    .build();
            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                queryProductDetailsParams,
                new ProductDetailsResponseListener(){
                    public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                            List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                                //Check billing result
                            }
                });
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected(){
        //Restart connection by calling the startConnection() method
    }
});

But from the logcat, I'm getting the warning "BillingLogger: Skipped logging since initialization failed"
How to go about this?
How to solve this since BillingClient is not getting initialized.
